# How to use multiple AND operators?

Tags: c#, list, if-statement, console-application, logical-operators

I have 6x `List<int>` : `PL1`, `PL2`, `PL3`, `PL4`, `PL5` and `PL6` and I want to call a function IF ALL of those Lists don't have a count of 6.

Example:

All lists except `PL4` have a count of 6 -> The function will execute.

All lists have a count of 6 -> The function will not execute.

I'm trying to achieve this with:

```
if (PL6.Count != 6 && PL5.Count != 6 && PL4.Count != 6 && PL3.Count != 6 && PL2.Count != 6 && PL1.Count != 6)
{
     Function();
}
```

.. which is not working. How do I get it to work? I tried `&`, `&&`, `|` and `||` in the statement.

Comment: Is the code above not working for you? Or are you looking for a cleaner method? You gotta tell us what you want. :)

Comment: That sounds like you want to use a logical OR instead of AND. Or negate the result of an entire chain of AND operations

Comment: Yea my method here is not working, I want to know how I can achieve what I wrote.
OR is also not working. I tried `&`, `&&`, `|` and `||`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the behaviour you're trying to capture is "execute the function if any of the lists don't have a count of 6". If this is your intent then you'll want the OR operator (`||`):

```
if (PL6.Count != 6 || PL5.Count != 6 || PL4.Count != 6 || PL3.Count != 6 || PL2.Count != 6 || PL1.Count != 6)
{
     Function();
}
```

Alternatively you could write this as:

```
if (!(PL6.Count == 6 && PL5.Count == 6 && PL4.Count == 6 && PL3.Count == 6 && PL2.Count == 6 && PL1.Count == 6))
{
     Function();
}
```

Comment: Your alternative did the trick for me! Thank you. I need to play around more with logical operators, it's still sometimes confusing for me.